# AngularJS promise and prevent redundant async calls

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a wcf service method that gets some data and I call it using Microsoft Ajax library. 
To share this data I create a dataService, and many controllers use this service.

I want every controller to get the same data after first call of getData is done, unless somebody need to refresh data and set forceRefresh to true.

My code fails because with the initialize of application 3 controler call dataService.getData and for all there start a new request. How can I make wait dataService.getData calls until the first one is finished and get same result for other subsequent ones..

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('dataService', function ($q) {
var data= [];   
var getData= function (forceRefresh) {
    console.log('getFolders called: ', reports.length);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (forceRefresh || data.length < 1) {

        WcfService.GetData(function(result) {
            data= result;
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }, function(ex) { console.log(ex); });

    } else {
                deferred.resolve(reports);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};

return {
    getData: getData
};
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found exactly what I search for

**Promise queue for AngularJS services**
http://inspectorit.com/tips-tricks/promise-queue-for-angularjs-services/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to cache the promise, rather than the data, so it gets cached when it is created and not when the data arrives. After all, this sounds like your use case.

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('dataService', function ($q) {
var deferred = null;
var getData= function (forceRefresh) {
    console.log('getFolders called: ', reports.length);
    if(!forceRefresh && deferred) return deferred.promise;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    WcfService.GetData(
        function(result) { deferred.resolve(data); }, // I'd promisify at a
        function(ex){ deferred.reject(ex); }          // higher level probably
    );

    return deferred.promise;
};

return {
    getData: getData
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about setting a global flag in the $rootscope when a controller is querying for data, which can be checked before fetching the data by all the controllers, hence, avoiding redundant calls. The same flag can be put down when any of the controller has the promise fulfilled and data has been fetched, which can then be shared amongst all the controllers.

Comment: Then the first controller gets the data, while others gets noting? Can you write some code..